# Calculating number of nonzero elements in any symbolic matrix

Tags: symbolic, elements

```
ClearAll[p, d]
Format[p[a_, b_]] := Subscript[p, Row@{a, b}]
d = 2
p[a_, a_] := 0;
p[a_, b_] := -p[b, a] /; (a > b)
pMat = Array[p, {2*d, 2*d}]
MatrixForm[pMat]
Length[Select[tMat, # != 0 &]]
```

How to calculate number of nonzero elements in any symbolic matrix. I have given an example of one symbolic matrix p above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Count[pMat, Except @ 0, {2}]
```

> ```
> 12
> ```

```
Length[Select[Flatten @ pMat, # =!= 0 &]]
```

> ```
> 12
> ```

```
Length @ SparseArray[pMat]["NonzeroValues"]
```

> ```
> 12
> ```